# how to convert datetime format from '2021-01-09T00:00:00' LIKE 2021-01-09 in datatable

Tags: javascript, datetime, html-table, datatable, converters

I want to show my hours changed from sql to 2021-01-09 00: 00: 00.000 as 2021-01-09. This date is filling up in the datatable, how can I change it?

Comment: Would `'2021-01-09 00: 00: 00.000'.split(' ')[0]` work?

Answer (score 0):

If the date is in string format you could just use the first 10 characters to achieve this goal, like this:

```
'2021-01-09 00: 00: 00.000'.slice(0, 10)
```

If it's in a Date object, then this could do the trick as well:

```
date.toISOString().slice(0, 10)
```

This could also be achieved directly from the SQL, using MySQL for example:

```
SELECT CAST(DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m-%d") AS char);
```